# Unpublished user in sns even if has full administrative permission, lambda out of vpc

Tags: yaml, amazon-sns, serverless

Good night I have a serious problem when trying to publish in a sns topic, my user has full access and still not publish. I am aware that if the lambda is in a vpc then I would have problems publishing to sns, however I separated my vpc lambda from the internet access lambdas, I use invoke to access the vpc, the lambda that publishes in sns is out of vpc and I can not publish in sns. Anyone with this problem?

> message:

```
{
 "code": 1072,
 "message": "User: arn:aws:iam::{accountID}:user/s3_developer is not authorized to perform: SNS:Publish on resource: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:{accountID}:snsMailSend"
}
```

The user s3_developer has full access admin, but still does not post to sns.

> My iam

```
iamRoleStatements:
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - lambda:InvokeFunction
    - lambda:InvokeAsync
  Resource: "*"
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - s3:GetObject
    - s3:ListBucket
    - s3:PutObject
  Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::"
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - ses:SendEmail
    - ses:SendRawEmail
  Resource: "arn:aws:ses:::"
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - sns:*
  Resource: "*"
```

SNS Trigger and create in lambda
var enviroment = "SNS_TOPIC": "snsMailSend"

```
sendMail:
  handler: lib/controllers/smtp/send.emailSend
  events:
    - sns: ${self:custom.secrets.SNS_TOPIC}
```

The topic is successfully created, I can publish by a simple lambda, but I can not publish my application where is the lambda that has the trigger and the lambda that publishes. I don't know what's wrong, does anyone see a light?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved, I created a specific user for SNS gave proper privileges and when instantiating sns I pass your user access and secrets, resolved. I saw that other people with similar problems hope this helps.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk')
const sns = new aws.SNS({ region: process.env.REGION, accessKeyId: process.env.SNS_KEY, secretAccessKey: process.env.SNS_SECRET })
```